# Trouble Setting Up MongoDB with SSL

Tags: mongodb, ssl

EDIT: I have gotten this to work when I connect remote from a machine, but for some reason it does not work when trying to connect via localhost

I'm trying to setup MongoDB with SSL. When I type in an IP address it tells me that the request was rejected because the name does not match the certificate. When I type in the correct machine name I get this error:

> SSL tunnel failure: Network is unreachable or SSL connection rejected
>   by server.

Any ideas how I could troubleshoot this further? I'm surprised that the server because I thought SSL is validated at the client.

I have tried changing ports, but have not had much luck.

Windows environment. MongoDB 3.4.4

I've got this working with localhost and a self signed certificate.

The windows firewall is off

Here are my settings:

```
security:
    authorization: "enabled"
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: c:\data\log\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: c:\data\db
net:
    bindIp: 0.0.0.0
    port: 443
    ssl:
       mode: requireSSL
       PEMKeyFile: c:\Cert\pemkeyfile.pem
       PEMKeyPassword: password
       CAFile: c:\Cert\cafile.pem
       allowInvalidHostnames: true
       allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true
       allowInvalidCertificates: true
```

Here is the mongo log

```
2018-07-26T15:13:01.878-0700 I CONTROL  [main] Trying to start Windows service 'MongoDB'
2018-07-26T15:13:01.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3900 port=443 dbpath=c:\data\db 64-bit host=CACALDDGNLP001
2018-07-26T15:13:01.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2018-07-26T15:13:01.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.4
2018-07-26T15:13:01.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 888390515874a9debd1b6c5d36559ca86b44babd
2018-07-26T15:13:01.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016
2018-07-26T15:13:01.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-07-26T15:13:01.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-07-26T15:13:01.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-07-26T15:13:01.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2018-07-26T15:13:01.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-07-26T15:13:01.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-07-26T15:13:01.880-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\mongod.cfg", net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0", port: 443, ssl: { CAFile: "c:\Cert\cafile.pem", PEMKeyFile: "c:\Cert\pemkeyfile.pem", PEMKeyPassword: "<password>", allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true, allowInvalidCertificates: true, allowInvalidHostnames: true, mode: "requireSSL" } }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, service: true, storage: { dbPath: "c:\data\db" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "c:\data\log\mongod.log" } }
2018-07-26T15:13:01.883-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in c:\data\db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2018-07-26T15:13:01.884-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1535M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2018-07-26T15:13:02.487-0700 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'c:/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2018-07-26T15:13:02.488-0700 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 443 ssl
2018-07-26T15:13:02.488-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Service running
```

Comment: What does the log at `c:\data\log\mongod.log` show?

Comment: In MongoDB, the default in `requireSSL` means that SSL identity is validated in both the client and the server. The server would also need to know that the client is who they say they are, unlike the normal web browser SSL that doesn't need to validate the client. Additional questions: 1) what is the hostname defined in the SSL certificate (both the client's and the server's)? 2) what is the command line options you use in the `mongo` shell that failed to connect? 3) I advise you not to use port 443 since it is well known as the `https` port.

Comment: I set allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true and it now connects. The only place it does not connect is on the local machine for some reason. Remote connections work. I am using Robomongo to connect it is a GUI. The hostname in the cert is the same as the servername alone and also the fully qualified domain name. Putting it to 443 was one of those desperate troubleshooting steps. It works with 27017.

Comment: Is connecting from localhost still an issue? I'm not familiar with RoboMongo, but I think the reason why connecting with `allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true` is because RoboMongo does not/cannot provide the client's SSL certificate. SSL is very picky about hostnames. The client certificate's `CN` must match the client's hostname, and the server's certificate's `CN` must match the server's hostname. From localhost, you can presumably use the same certificate in both the client and the server by setting `--sslPEMKeyFile` to be the same in `mongod` and the `mongo` shell.

Comment: Connecting from the same server is still an issue. I'm not actually using localhost int he address. I'm using the FQDN for the server which should match the cert. For some reason it doesn't work though.